# Count duplicate property values of a nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm feeding in information in from an API with the format -

```
Records = { 0: {fields: {name: "nameExample" place: "placeExample"} }
{1: {fields: {name: "nameExample" place: "placeExample"} }
```

etc etc

I'm looking for a way to count duplicates of the 'place' field in the format: Scotland(4), London(6) etc. where the number is the amount of times it repeats.

The closest I've got as of yet is counting the letters in each place name, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think if I can get them in the same array then it would be simple, but when I tried to do that it put each place in a different array.

Also must be vanilla javaScript, no jQuery. Many thanks!

```js
  var URL = new Array();
  URL[0] = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q=a&limit=45";
  URL[1] = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q=a&limit=45&offset=45";
  URL[2] = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q=a&limit=45&offset=90";
  var nRequest = new Array();
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
     (function(i) {
        nRequest[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nRequest[i].open("GET", URL[i], true);
        nRequest[i].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
           if (nRequest[i].readyState === 4) {
              if (nRequest[i].status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(nRequest[i].responseText);
                var url = 'http://media.vam.ac.uk/media/thira/collection_images/';
                for (let key in data.records) {
                    let value = data.records[key];
                    let image = value.fields.primary_image_id;
                    let res = image.substr(0, 6);
                    document.querySelector(".map").innerHTML += '<div class="' + value.fields.place + ' map"> <a href="map.html">' + value.fields.place + '</a> <br> </div>';

            }

          } else {
                console.log("Error", nRequest[i].statusText);
              }

           }

      //

        };
        nRequest[i].send(null);

     })(i);

  };
```

Comment: To get an array of places: `var places = Records.map(x => x.fields.place)` (assuming `Records` is actually an array, if not: `Object.values`).

Comment: What kind of data structure is that Records? can u please provide us valid javascript code?

Comment: is the information you get back in an array?

Comment: Added to original post @Mischa - the Records data structure is fed in from https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject

Answer (score 2):

If [thats the data structure](https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/) you can solve it like so:

```js
const Records = [
  {fields: {name: "nameExample", place: "placeExample"}},
  {fields: {name: "nameExample", place: "placeExample"}}
];

const result = Records.reduce((acc, {fields}) => {
  if(acc[fields.place]) acc[fields.place]++;
  else acc[fields.place] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Apologies if I'm being stupid, I'm a beginner with working with API data structures. This works well in terms of counting the place field but how do I feed the data from the API into the 'const Records'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function to convert the array `data.records` to an object with the place as key and number of occurrences as value.

```
data.records.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    if (!(currVal.fields.place in accum)){
        accum[currVal.fields.place] = 0;
    } 
    accum[currVal.fields.place] += 1;
    return accum;
}, {});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Returned this error - TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined

Comment: @roman74 did you copy it entirely? Including the curly braces on the last line?

Comment: I did, just double checked and still returning the same error.